# View events are firing multiple times after navigating views

Tags: android, actionscript-3, apache-flex, mobile, air

I made a basic Air/Flex app that has a Home View and a 2nd View and attached mxml events for activate and deactivate onto each of them. From the home view there is a button that pushes the 2nd view. If I suspend and reopen the app from the Home View, the deactivate and activate events fire once each. Then, if I go to the 2nd view and do the same thing, the activate/deactivate events from the Home View fire alongside the ones from the 2nd view. When I go back to the Home view and repeat the test, 3 sets of activate/deactivate events fire (2 from home, 1 from 2nd) and this keeps going. Why is this happening and how do I prevent it? Am I doing something wrong here?

I've tested this in Air 3.3-3.5 on an android 2.3 device and on the desktop tester.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are somehow using Event.ACTIVATE event instead of FlexEvent.VIEW_ACTIVATE

ACTIVATE event is dispatched when your app gains focus from os. It a broadcast event - each eventdispatcher will fire it. So, all your views will dispatch it.

Views are recycled, so, when you open home view second time, it seems that there is a new copy that you actually see on screen and an old copy that is waiting offscreen for garbage collection, still receiveing events. So, that's why you have two events from home view.

You may read http://corlan.org/2011/01/12/understanding-flex-mobile-views-and-viewnavigator/ this for more details on view lifecycle.